# Does it Build? - A virtualbox image to build software packages successfully

Tags: build, build-process, virtualbox

I would like to set up a minimal Linux system which has nothing else to do then building software packages. But reliably and successfully!

**Goal:**
Set up and provide publicly a virtualbox image and a set of instructions for major software packages that clearly run through the whole build process successfully and create a reliable basis for interested people to start understanding the package.

**1. First important question. Is there something already existing?**

It doesn't make sense to invent the wheel many times. I have done a little bit of research but didn't really find something to my taste.
 Do you know anything that's already there?

**2. How should I start?**

**Virtualbox.**
Setting up Virtualbox is easy. 
I have worked quite a bit with Virtualbox. But is it the right choice?

**Basic Linux.**
There are many linux flavors. Especially in such a case where only the building features are required. A gui is definitely not necessary, so the footprint could be a lot smaller. I first thought about Mini Ubuntu but at the second thought that is just a smaller cd image to install the whole ubuntu from the internet. The next thought was about ubuntu server edition. That's a CD with 670 MB. Why is it so big? I also remember that I one worked with LFS... Goal should be that it's limited effort to create a system that can build the main software packages without problems...

**3. More suggestions how to proceed?**

...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your purpose is pretty much the same as the purpose of the [Open Build Service](http://openbuildservice.org/about/) for which you can [download the installer ISO](http://openbuildservice.org/download/). Then if you like, you can install within VirtualBox onto a virtual hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

you can probably find what you need here,

http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/

after you can just add your required tools and rezip it for distribution..

But you should add more details of what you plan to do... what kind of package for what kind of distributions ...